# In pig I want to reduce groups to have 1 element with specific types having precedence

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In pig, I have columns A, B, C, id, id_type. The possible id_types are "zip," "city," "county," "state," and "country."

I wish to make it so that there exists only one instance of each existing A, B, C, but giving precedence to the row with id_type "zip," but if not "zip," then "city," and if not "city," then... etc.

So, if I have the following two rows

```
(a, b, c, 555, city)
(a, b, c, 123, state)
```

I want to remove the second one. I can group by A, B, C to get

```
({a, b, c}, {(a, b, c, 555, city), (a, b, c, 123, state)})
```

But I do not know how I can remove all of the unwanted elements from $1

Comment: This should actually be possible using a UDF, but I would really like if there were a way to do it without one.

Comment: you can add a value to each id_type.
For example zip 1, city 2,..etc
Then for each group order by ascending and limit 1.
Which will return only the first tuple from the bag thus removing the other tuples.

Eg: (a, b, c, 555, city,1)
(a, b, c, 123, state,2)

groupby and orderby returns:
({a, b, c}, {(a, b, c, 555, city,1), (a, b, c, 123, state,2)})

limit 1 returns 
({a, b, c}, {(a, b, c, 555, city,1)}).........

Lemme know if it works

Answer (score 0):

@inquistive_mind : I ran your code with following input and it DOES NOT return what is asked by OP

Input :

```
(aa,bb,cc,1,zip)
(aa,bb,cc,2,street)
(mmm,nnn,cc,3,county)
(mmm,nnn,cc,4,zip)
(mmm,nnn,cc,5,state)
(lll,ccc,ddd,6,city)
(lll,ccc,xxx,7,country)
```

Output after running your code :

```
((aa,bb,cc),{(2,country),(1,zip)})
((lll,ccc,ddd),{(6,city)})
((lll,ccc,xxx),{(7,country)})
((mmm,nnn,cc),{(5,state),(4,zip),(3,county)})
```

You clearly see it does not keep only one entry on the priority of id_type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a PYTHON UDF. If there are better way Please let me know

Python Code saved as priority.py

```
def unique_list(input):
    my_list = input
    last_list = []
    #print(my_list[0][4])
    #print(len(my_list))
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        last_list.append(my_list[i][4])


        print(last_list)
        for j in range(len(last_list)):
          if(last_list[j]) == "zip":
             return_list = list(my_list[j])
             break
          elif (last_list[j] == 'city'):
              return_list = list(my_list[j])
              break
          elif (last_list[j] == 'county'):
              return_list = list(my_list[j])
              break
          elif (last_list[j] == 'state'):
              return_list = list(my_list[j])
              break
          elif (last_list[j] == 'country'):
              return_list = list(my_list[j])
              break

 return return_list
```

Now The Pig Code

```
REGISTER 'priority.py' using jython as callme
A = LOAD 'addr.dat' USING PigStorage(',') AS (A : chararray, B :chararray , C:  chararray , ID :  chararray,  ID_TYPE :  chararray);

B = DISTINCT A;
Z=  GROUP B BY (A,B,C);
O = FOREACH Z GENERATE callme.unique_list($1) as record :{(A : chararray, B :chararray , C:  chararray , ID :  chararray,  ID_TYPE :  chararray)} ;
DUMP O;
```

Please run this against your input and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a UDF, another way is:

```
 ABC = load 'testdata.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (a: chararray, b: chararray, c: chararray, id: int, id_type: chararray);
MappedABC = foreach ABC generate a, b, c, id, id_type, (id_type == 'zip' ? 1 : (id_type == 'city' ?  2 : (id_type == 'county' ?  3 : (id_type == 'state' ?  4 : 5)))) as idorder;
FinalABC = foreach (group MappedABC by (a,b,c)) {
    OrderedABC = order MappedABC by idorder;
    LimitedABC = limit OrderedABC 1;
    generate
        flatten(LimitedABC)
    ;

};
store FinalABC into 'out' using PigStorage(';');
```